# How to find all values of $x$ for which $\sec x=-1$ is true?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Find all values of x for which the following is true.
$\sec x = -1$

a) π + 2kπ
b) (π/4) + 2kπ
c) 2kπ
d) (π/2) + kπ
e) -(π/3) + 2kπ

I know that $\sec \theta =\frac  1 {\cos \theta}$. I don't know what to do after that. I think the unit circle is involved somehow.

This is for my online trigonometry class, it's a homework problem and I can't figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For a): what is $\cos(\pi)$? What is $\cos(\pi + 2 k \pi)$?

Comment: cos(π) = -1. I don't know what the k means so I don't know how to answer your other question.

Comment: In trig contexts like this one it's usually defined (or assumed) that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an integer, so $2 k \pi$ is an integer multiple of $2 \pi$.

Comment: I still don't understand how to figure out cos(π + 2kπ). What does k equal? Sorry, bad at math.

Comment: $\cos(x)$ is a periodic function with period $2 \pi$. What this means is that $\cos(x)$ $=\cos(x+2 \pi)$ $= cos(x + 4 \pi) = \cdots$ for any $x$. This is usually written as $cos(x) = cos(x + 2 k \pi) \;\text{for}\; \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So, back to point **a)**: $\;\cos(\pi + 2 k \pi) = \cos(\pi)$.

Comment: @dxiv I think I understand.. but I don't know how to figure out if sec x = -1 is related to that or not. Like.. what is the first step? Or can you give me a random example to look at? I can only find 1 example on Google and it's badly explained/written.

Comment: `I know that sec theta = 1 / cos theta.` You know that. Then, you said in a comment that $\cos \pi = -1$, and just agreed that $\cos(\pi + 2 k \pi) = \cos(\pi) = -1$. So, it follows that $sec(\pi + 2 k \pi) = \frac{1}{\cos(\pi + 2 k \pi)} = -1$. With that, you just solved point **a)**. Repeat for the others.

Comment: @dxiv Oh okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\sec x=-1\iff\cos x=-1\iff x\equiv \pi\mod2\pi$.